# Is there a difference between a vegetable tray and a relish tray?

Tags: vegetables

Are pickles, beets and olives-green and black,radishes part of a relish tray? Where as carrots, cauliflower, celery, broccoli,small tomatoes are part of a vegetable tray. Right?

Comment: First time I hear about a "relish tray" after a quick googling it looks like a regionalim term equivalent to a "vegetable tray"
Also see this : https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91497/what-is-a-relish-tray-versus-a-veggie-tray

Comment: The terms tend to be largely interchangeable in my experience and somewhat regional, but yes, relish tray tends to be used a bit more often when preserved and pickled items are included, while vegetable tray seems more common when the tray is all or mostly fresh veggies.  I think few would consider either to ever be wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

A relish tray emphasizes, but isn't necessarily exclusively comprised of, preserved/pickled vegetables.